# Issue building UWP app using MSBuild (GENERATEPROJECTPRIFILE)

Tags: msbuild, uwp, cakebuild

I am trying to build a UWP app from the command-line in an effort to automate the builds from check-in to publishing to the store. Everything works fine when running the builds from within Visual Studio and when I create app packages, it all works fine (but takes too long, 15 minutes or so).

While invoking msbuild per platform (x86, x64 & ARM), only ARM seems to fail with the following error:

```
_CreatePriConfigXmlForSplitting

"C:\Source\MyProject\src\MyProject\MyProject.csproj" (Build target) (1) ->
(_SplitResourcesPri target) ->
  error PRI175 : 0x80070002 - Processing Resources failed with error : The system cannot find the file specified. [C:\Source\MyProject\src\MyProject\MyProject.csproj]
  GENERATEPROJECTPRIFILE : error PRI252: 0xdef00071 - File C:\Source\MyProject\output\Release\x86\arm\MyProject\resources.pri not found. [C:\Source\MyProject\src\MyProject\MyProject.csproj]

    0 Warning(s)
    2 Error(s)
```

As you probably noticed, it's using `x86\arm` directory instead of `arm`, hence the build is failing.

I am using [Cake](http://cakebuild.net/) to build this, below is (relevant part of) the script:

```
Task("Build")
    .IsDependentOn("Clean")
    .IsDependentOn("UpdateVersion")
    .IsDependentOn("RestorePackages")
    .Does(() =>
{
    var platforms = new Dictionary<string, PlatformTarget>();
    platforms["ARM"] = PlatformTarget.ARM;
    platforms["x86"] = PlatformTarget.x86;
    platforms["x64"] = PlatformTarget.x64;

    foreach (var platform in platforms)
    {
        Information("Building project for platform {0}", platform.Key);

        var outputDirectory = "../../" + outputRootDirectory + "/" + platform.Value.ToString();
        var projectFileName = string.Format("./src/{0}/{0}.csproj", solutionName);

        var msBuildSettings = new MSBuildSettings {
            Verbosity = Verbosity.Diagnostic, // Verbosity.Minimal
            ToolVersion = MSBuildToolVersion.VS2017,
            Configuration = configurationName,
            MSBuildPlatform = MSBuildPlatform.x86, // Always require x86, see platform for actual target platform
            PlatformTarget = platform.Value
        };

        // Need special path since this is relative to the project file, not the cake build directory
        //msBuildSettings.Properties["OutputPath"] = new List<string>(new [] { outputDirectory });

        // We don't create native builds, we will use MSIL builds which the store will recompile,
        // for more info see https://oren.codes/2015/12/03/continuous-integration-for-uwp-projects-making-builds-faster/
        msBuildSettings.Properties["UseDotNetNativeToolchain"] = new List<string>(new [] { "false" });
        msBuildSettings.Properties["BuildAppxUploadPackageForUap"] = new List<string>(new [] { "true" });
        //msBuildSettings.Properties["AppxPackageArtifactsDir"] = new List<string>(new [] { outputDirectory });

        // Fix for broken targets
        //msBuildSettings.Properties["ProjectPriFileName"] = new List<string>(new [] { "resources.pri" });
        //msBuildSettings.Properties["ProjectPriFullPath"] = new List<string>(new [] { outputDirectory + "/resources.pri" });
        //msBuildSettings.Properties["_TransformedProjectPriFullPath"] = new List<string>(new [] { outputDirectory + "/resources.pri" });

        MSBuild(projectFileName, msBuildSettings);
    }
});
```

A. As you can see I am experimenting a bit by manually overriding the ms build properties, but no luck so far.

B. At first I thought it was `GenerateProjectPriFile` task that was failing. However, after some investigation I found out that creating the split files already show use the wrong `startIndexAt` value:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources targetOsVersion="10.0.0" majorVersion="1">
  <packaging>
    <autoResourcePackage qualifier="Language" />
    <autoResourcePackage qualifier="Scale" />
    <autoResourcePackage qualifier="DXFeatureLevel" />
    <omitSchemaFromResourcePacks />
  </packaging>
  <index root="\" startIndexAt="C:\Source\MyProject\output\Release\x86\arm\MyProject\resources.pri">
    <default>
      <qualifier name="Language" value="en-US" />
      <qualifier name="Contrast" value="standard" />
      <qualifier name="Scale" value="200" />
      <qualifier name="HomeRegion" value="001" />
      <qualifier name="TargetSize" value="256" />
      <qualifier name="LayoutDirection" value="LTR" />
      <qualifier name="DXFeatureLevel" value="DX9" />
      <qualifier name="Configuration" value="" />
      <qualifier name="AlternateForm" value="" />
      <qualifier name="Platform" value="UAP" />
    </default>
    <indexer-config type="PRI" />
  </index>
</resources>
```

I have no idea why it prepends x86 before ARM when building for ARM. Any help is appreciated. In the meantime I'll continue investigating and update this post if I find something new.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like I have to specify the `sln` file, not the `csproj` file. This is a bit unfortunate since now it builds much more than it needs to (there are multiple projects in the same solution), but I can get around that by creating a custom `MyProject.Build.sln` file

Comment: So to clarify.. Is this a Cake issue, or is this an issue when building directly from the command line as well?

Comment: Not a cake issue, it's msbuild magic of which I can't find any decent documentation (but that can still be me)