# TFS check-in error on UWP 1803+. How to configure TFS?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs, uwp

I have a solution with `UWP` projects, min and target version `1803 (17134)`.

Formerly I've had compilation errors:

> CA0055: Could not identify platform for {path}
>
> CA0052: No targets were selected,

Then I unchecked `Enable Code Analysis on Build` in projects settings and installed `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers` NuGet package as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55189683/uwp-app-compilation-error-pri175-with-0xdef00071).

But when I'm trying to check in to TFS I have the following errors:

> The following check-in policies were not satisfied

- The Code Analysis settings for one or more projects ar not compatible with Code Analysis policy.
- One or more projects do not have up-to-date Code Analysis results.

I guess TFS settings need to be updated to work with FxCop.

I'm using VS 2019 & TFS 2015.
Please help to configure TFS or find any solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have Code analysis policy, you need to disable/remove it.

1. In VS open the team explorer and click on "Settings":

[image]

2. Then click on "Source Control":

[image]

3. Go to "Check-in Policy" and Remove/Disable the Code Analysis policy:

[image]